# How to create a Local MongoDB _id

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, mongodb

I'm creating an offline app that create users locally and when the app is online I want to sync the created users to my remote mongodb database. So my question is there any plugin preferably in angular that creates a local mongodb _id?

Answer (score 3):

You can use any unique id for a **_id** field. However, if you do not specify _id field at all in your data, MongoDB will itself create a **_id** field with **ObjectID type** in documents.

Still, if you need to create ObjectId in your application, you can do it on the server.

It depends on the driver you are using for MongoDB connectivity.

If you are using **NodeJS driver for MongoDB**, then you can do it like this.

[Reference](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html)

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var objectId = new ObjectID();
```

If you are using **mongoose** for  MongoDB object modeling in NodeJS, then you can do it like this

[Mongoose Reference for types](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-Types)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
```

For Python MongoDB driver, refer this - [pymongo ObjectId](http://api.mongodb.com/python/1.7/api/pymongo/objectid.html)

I hope you can create ObjectId using other drivers as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any unique id, but if you want to create normal mongo `ObjectId` you can use the following npm package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/objectid or download the source from https://github.com/jsdnxx/objectid/releases/

then use the following:

```
// require in objectid
var objectid = require('objectid')

// Create an object Id
var id = objectid()
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, you can use any unique value as an _id. If you don't send this value one will be created by the mongo server.